# How can i generate an Angular routing URL for only one time used

Tags: angular

im trying to create an angular project that contain the online paiement with stripe , when the user finish his payment checkout , it return him to a success page (component ) with a generated routing parameter. i want to know if can i do that this route it open only one time and will never opened if the user want to opened in other time

exemple

http://localhost:4200/Paiement?F48FZeg758ae

Comment: Please add code from example. Because we can't see your example on localhost (only you can see)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many ways in Angular however the most simple is using the Angular Router.  You can use Activated Route and listen to the snapshot data, but that's incredibly complex compared to just getting the id from url which is ultimately what you want I think?

edit **app-router.module.ts**

```
{path: 'paiement/:id', component: PaiementComponent}
```

edit **paiement.component.ts**

```
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const yourid = this.router.url.split('/').pop()
    // now you can do something with that id
    // there are many ways to do this but its probably
    // the most simple this way

    
  }
```

https://angular.io/guide/router
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute